# Std::bind clarification

Tags: c++

```
std::sort(std::begin(people), std::end(people),
          std::bind(std::less<>{},
                    std::bind(&Person::year_of_birth, _1),
                    std::bind(&Person::year_of_birth, _2)));
```

Person is a class that has member year_of_birth on which we need to sort.
I don't understand how internal binds work here (_1 and _2). Is it possible to bind with _2 for a class member ?

Comment: No, those are invalid names. You can't start a name with a number. The underscore you can, but needs a letter following it not  a number.: `_p1`,

Comment: @EvanCarslake `std::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: `std::bind` fixes parameters within a function. In your case, you take a binary `std:less<class T> ()` operator and convert it to a non-parametrised function. 
This is not what `sort` expects - it does need a binary function. If your intent is to sort people by they year of birth, you can either use a lambda function, or add a custom `operator <` to your `Person` class.

Comment: @RomanK Yes, I could but this also works also. The question was about the internals/how

Comment: Apologies, you're right - this is the "bind to member data" rather than "bind  to a value" option, I missed it the first time around.

I suspect it works in a very similar way to binding to member functions, i.e. the compiler inserts a wrapper that calls a function (or, as the case here, access a variable at specific offset) before calling the wrapped function. Of course, not being a compiler implementer, can't confirm 100%.